# How to remove "index.php" from Transcribe's language prefix

Tags: multi-language, transcribe

I am using Transcribe add-on which does a good job in managing a multi lingual site. I would like to take advantage of the option to include the language abbreviation as a prefix on the url but having problems with producing a "clean" url for pages with language prefix.

For example, with the language prefix switched on ("es" for Spanish), the system generates these types of urls domain-name.com/index.php/es/page-name instead of domain-name.com/page-name. I would like to use the prefix without the "index.php" that preceeds it but not sure how to.

I already have the normal bit of htaccess code that removes "index.php" from tempalte groups.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it to work:

With the add-on language prefix option turned on, the add-on prefixes urls with “index.php/es” like this http://domain-name.com/index.php/es, http://domain-name.com/index.php/es/page-name, etc. I created a new template group called “es” and it seems the existing htaccess code that removes “index.php” from templates groups has dealt with it. So now these links with just the language prefix work http://domain-name.com/es and http://domain-name.com/es/page-name.